# Python File ending with .py~

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python
What is the meaning of `.py~(ending with ~)` and It is generated automatically.
why it is generated automatically?can I delete this file?

Comment: Most likely it is some form of backup file in your text editor. `*.py~` are not defined in Python specification.

Comment: Which text editor are you using?

Comment: it sounds like you are using vim or emacs or something simillar ... thats just a temporary backup while editing

Comment: will it affect my actual python program if delete it?

Comment: I am using sublime-text2 editor

Comment: If you have several terminal sessions running at the same time, you could have an editor running in one and running command-line tests in another.  Deleting the file will not affect the python, but it could affect your editor.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for